# Custom Lambda sort extension

Tags: c#, list, lambda

i want to use my custom extension method to order a list of objects. it's just a sample so it uses a bubblesort. my current state:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByBubbleSort<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    IComparer<TSource> comparer = Comparer<TSource>.Default;
    List<TSource> Result = source.ToList();
    for (int i = (source.Count() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (comparer.Compare(Result[j - 1], Result[j]) > 0)
            {
                var temp = Result[j - 1];
                Result[j - 1] = Result[j];
                Result[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)Result;
}
```

so i can call it that way:

```
List<Person> pList = ...
List<Person> Result = pList.OrderByBubbleSort(x => x.Age).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

I'm stuck with the `keySelector`. I need to compare the items by the selected property (e.g. `Age`)

Question: What's how is the correct syntax for my comparer?

Comment: you know that this will never be `IOrderedQueryable` right?

Comment: You should check Jon Skeet's [EduLinq series](*http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/), especially the part about implementing [IOrderedEnumerable](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/04/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26a-iorderedenumerable/) and  [OrderBy/ThenBy](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/05/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26b-orderby-descending-thenby-descending/)

Comment: As written, you can't do the `ThenBy` part. To do it, you need to "delay" the ordering until the last of the `ThenBy` has been encountered

Comment: As you'll see in Jon's series, there's actually a *lot* of stuff you're missing for an `OrderBy` implementation.

Comment: OrderBy takes three blog posts in Jon's series, with a custom algorithm (MergeSort) introduced only in the [third part](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/06/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26c-optimizing-orderedenumerable/). You need to create your own OrderedEnumerable (part 1) that sorts using your custom algorithm (part 2) and create composable OrderBy and ThenBy methods (part 2). The actual work is done by the custom OrderedEnumerable, not the extension methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now... Doing correctly a `OrderBy` as other said is difficult... this is an implementation I wrote in 15 minutes...

```
public static class MyOrderedEnumerable
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MyOrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (keySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        }

        Comparison<TSource> comparer2 = (x, y) => comparer.Compare(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
        return new OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource>(source, comparer2);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MyOrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (keySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        }

        Comparison<TSource> comparer2 = (x, y) => comparer.Compare(keySelector(y), keySelector(x));
        return new OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource>(source, comparer2);
    }

    private class OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource> : IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<TSource> Source;
        private readonly Comparison<TSource> Comparer;

        public OrderedEnumerableImpl(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Comparison<TSource> comparer)
        {
            Source = source;
            Comparer = comparer;
        }

        public IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>(Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending)
        {
            if (comparer == null)
            {
                comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
            }

            Comparison<TSource> comparer2;

            if (descending)
            {
                comparer2 = (x, y) =>
                {
                    int result = Comparer(x, y);
                    if (result == 0)
                    {
                        result = comparer.Compare(keySelector(y), keySelector(x));
                    }
                    return result;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                comparer2 = (x, y) =>
                {
                    int result = Comparer(x, y);
                    if (result == 0)
                    {
                        result = comparer.Compare(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
                    }
                    return result;
                };
            }

            return new OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource>(Source, comparer2);
        }

        public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var source = Source.ToArray();

            // ** Here you do the sorting! **
            Array.Sort(source, Comparer);

            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return source[i];
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

See the `** Here you do the sorting! **`? There you have to plug your sort algorithm. As you can see, there is an `OrderedEnumerableImpl` class that does the implementation. The point is that the `ThenBy` uses the `CreateOrderedEnumerable` method. This method modifies the sorting algorithm, by chaining its comparer to the base comparer of the `OrderBy`. **but** there is a point here: you can't really modify the ordering, because one could:

```
var myorderedcoll = mycoll.OrderBy(x => x.Foo);
var mysubordered1 = myorderedcoll.ThenBy(x => x.Bar1);
var mysubordered2 = myorderedcoll.ThenBy(x => x.Bar2);
```

Clearly `mysubordered1` is ordered by `Foo+Bar1`, while `mysubordered2` is ordered by `Foo+Bar2`!

So `CreateOrderedEnumerable` creates a new `OrderedEnumerableImpl` class, by taking the comparer already present and adding the new comparer (see the last line of `CreateOrderedEnumerable`)

Note that you use this class as:

```
var myorderedcoll = mycoll.MyOrderBy(x => x.Foo).ThenBy(x => x.Bar);
```

and so on.

**Note that a "real" implementation is much more complex. As written, this implementation recalculates the `key` each time it does a comparison. Real implementations precalculate all the necessary keys to speedup the comparisons.**

For the sorting, using the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation):

```
public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
{
    var source = Source.ToArray();

    // Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation

    int n = source.Length;

    do
    {
        int newn = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Comparer(source[i - 1], source[i]) > 0)
            {
                TSource temp = source[i - 1];
                source[i - 1] = source[i];
                source[i] = temp;
                newn = i;
            }
        }

        n = newn;
    }
    while (n != 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return source[i];
    }
}
```

This too could be optimized: if we reverse the bubblesort and accumulate the ordered elements in the "top" of the array, then we can for each cycle of bubblesort `yield return` one element. This will shorten the time needed to have the first element. So if you do `OrderBy(x => x.Foo).First()`, not all the collection will be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `comparer.Compare(Result[j - 1], Result[j])` now. That is wrong, since it doesn't take the key into account as you said.

You should get the key by calling the `Func keySelector`, and match that one:

```
IComparer<TKey> comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;

var x = keySelector(Result[j - 1]);
var y = keySelector(Result[j]);

if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll say that the null check are conceptually wrong. If there is no key selector, then a `ArgumentNullException` is called for. The `OrderBy` does it. And perhaps add that `IComparer<TSource> comparer = Comparer<TSource>.Default;` should be `TKey` based