# Insertion sort in one method using class object

Tags: c#, .net

I am building my lab for college and I am new to .net framwork. I wanna to sort the data but I need to follow certain rule for this lab one of them is I can not use list it has to be array.

Here is my menu

```
 1 - Sort by Employee Name (ascending)
 2 - Sort by Employee Number (ascending)
 3 - Sort by Employee Pay Rate (descending)
 4 - Sort by Employee Hours (descending)
 5 - Sort by Employee Gross Pay (descending)
 6 - Exit
```

I have a data in model class and I store data in my employees array. I shorted my menu 2 but I need global function for all menu.

**Sorting code**

```
for (int i = 1; i < employees.Length; i++)
{
    Employee current = employees[i];

    int j = i - 1;
    for (; j >= 0 && current.GetNumber() > employees[j].GetNumber(); j--)
    {
        employees[j + 1] = employees[j];
    }
    employees[j + 1] = current;
}

foreach (Employee employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(employee);
}
```

> Question : Is there any way that I can make one function that gives me
>   different output for each menu because It is criteria that i can use
>   one function to complete the all menu.

If need anything from my side please comment.

Comment: You should have to use LINQ.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I found solution on internet but it's in list or LINQ. But i am looking for array.

Comment: I would suggest that the best solution would be to define an `EmployeeComparer` class that implements `IComparer(Of Employee)` and allows you to specify which property to sort by.  You can then simply create an instance of that class and specify the desired property, then pass it to `Array.Sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegates to solve your problem. So you will have a common method to sort your array that will also accept the delegate on how to compare 2 Employees:

```
public Employee[] Sort(Employee[] employees, Func<Employee, Employee, bool> comparer)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < employees.Length; i++)
    {
        Employee current = employees[i];

        int j = i - 1;
        for (; j >= 0 && comparer(current,employees[j]); j--)
        {
            employees[j + 1] = employees[j];
        }
        employees[j + 1] = current;
    }

    return employees;
}
```

And an example of usage will be

```
Sort(employees, (e1, e2) => e1.GetNumber() > e2.GetNumber())
```

or

```
Sort(employees, (e1, e2) => string.Compare(e1.Name, e2.Name) < 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code. One can retrieve property and then use it:

```
public void Sort(Employee[] employees, string propertyName)
{
        var desiredProperty = typeof(Employee).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        PropertyInfo info = typeof(Employee).GetProperty(propertyName);

        if (info == null) { return; }

        for (int i = 1; i < employees.Length; i++)
        {
            Employee current = employees[i];

            int j = i - 1;
            int curValue = Convert.ToInt32(info.GetValue(current));
            int prevValue = Convert.ToInt32(info.GetValue(employees[j]));

            for (; j >= 0 && curValue > prevValue; j--)
            {
                employees[j + 1] = employees[j];
            }

            employees[j + 1] = current;
        }

        foreach (Employee employee in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info.GetValue(employee));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create extention class

```
public static class OrderedEnumerable
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (keySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        }

        Comparison<TSource> comparer2 = (x, y) => comparer.Compare(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
        return new OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource>(source, comparer2);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (keySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        }

        Comparison<TSource> comparer2 = (x, y) => comparer.Compare(keySelector(y), keySelector(x));
        return new OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource>(source, comparer2);
    }

    private class OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource> : IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<TSource> Source;
        private readonly Comparison<TSource> Comparer;

        public OrderedEnumerableImpl(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Comparison<TSource> comparer)
        {
            Source = source;
            Comparer = comparer;
        }

        public IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>(Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending)
        {
            if (comparer == null)
            {
                comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
            }

            Comparison<TSource> comparer2;

            if (descending)
            {
                comparer2 = (x, y) =>
                {
                    int result = Comparer(x, y);
                    if (result == 0)
                    {
                        result = comparer.Compare(keySelector(y), keySelector(x));
                    }
                    return result;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                comparer2 = (x, y) =>
                {
                    int result = Comparer(x, y);
                    if (result == 0)
                    {
                        result = comparer.Compare(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
                    }
                    return result;
                };
            }

            return new OrderedEnumerableImpl<TSource>(Source, comparer2);
        }

        public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var source = Source.ToArray();

            // ** Here you do the sorting! **
            Array.Sort(source, Comparer);

            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return source[i];
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

and Use like as follow

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int GrossPay { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int PayRate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}




void Main()
{
    var Employee = new Employee[] { new Employee { Name = "acb", Number = 123 }, new Employee { Name = "nmo", Number = 456 }, new Employee { Name = "xyz", Number = 789 } };
    var sortedEmpByNum = Employee.OrderBy(x => x.Number);// by number asc
    var sortedEmpByNubDesc = Employee.OrderByDescending(x => x.Number); //by number desc
    var sortedEmpByName = Employee.OrderBy(x => x.Name); //by name asc

    //you shoud use this one
    var finalResult = Employee.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Number)
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.PayRate)
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Hours)
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.GrossPay);
}
```

credit=> [custom-lambda-sort-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675693/custom-lambda-sort-extension)